# Definition of Tychonoff Separation Property in Royden's Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, separation-axioms

In the fourth edition of Royden's *Real Analysis* (Section 11.2) he defines the Tychonoff Separation Property by

> **Tychonoff Separation Property** For each two points $u$ and $v$ in $X$, there is a neighborhood of $u$ that does not contain $v$ and a neighborhood of $v$ that does not contain $u$.

However this seems to actually be the definition of the $T_1$ separation property according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom) Wikipedia article as well as other texts such as Knapp's *Basic Real Analysis*. Am I mistaken about the discrepancy or does Royden just define Tychonoff separation differently?

Comment: No, you are not wrong.

Comment: That article is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. I would not like to use the phrase "Tychonoff Separation Property" as a synonym for $T_1$, but we must be aware that mathematical notation is not standardized. Sometimes it even has a geographic or cultural background. For example, there is a topological space known as the "Moore plane" in the United States and as the "Niemytzki plane" in Eastern Europe.

Concerning notational variants of separation axioms see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom.